Can a child data fetcher be avoided if a return type from a parent data fetcher is different?
I am looking for a piece of advice regarding my GQL schema and Data Fetchers which were registered in Spring application with annotations.
I have two data fetchers for a favoritePet field and for an owner field.
My question is It's possible to not call the data fetcher for owner field if QueryError type is returned from the parent data fetcher(in this case it's favoritePet)?
If the answer is yes, how it can be implemented?
type Query {
    favoritePet(name: String!): Pet
}

type Pet {
    name(error: QueryError): String
    owner: Owner
}

union Owner = Person | QueryError

type Person {
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
}

input QueryError {
 message: String
 statusCode: Int

 }


@Controller
record PetsController(PetService petService) {

  @QueryMapping
  Object favoritePet(String name) {
     if(validateName(name)) {
        return new QueryError(); 
       }

    return petService.getFavoritePetByName(name); //Pet type
  }

  @SchemaMapping(typeName = "Pet", field = "owner")
  Object owner(Object petOrQueryError) {

    if(petOrQueryError instqanceOf QueryError){
       return petOrQueryError;
      }

    Pet pet = (Pet) petOrQueryError;
    return petService.getPerson(pet.ownerId()); // Person type
  }

}

